# Is there any way to insert a hyper link to kusto query result?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

```
cluster('aaa').database('bbb').CustomFieldEntries
| project Id
| extend Link = "<a href=\"https://aka.ms" target=\"_blank\">Link</a>"
```

It's a wrong example and will not show "Link" with hyper link, it will display as the original string. But how to do that?

Comment: You expect your client (Kusto Explorer / Kusto Web Explorer?) to act as a web browser and interpretate your data as a code instead of displaying it As Is? **P.S.** **(1)** This code will result in parsing error due to wrong use of qualifiers. **(2)** If you want to demonstrate something you can simply use the *print* or *datatable* operators.

Answer (score 0):

The default web explorer supports clickable links in its settings.
However, if you're using a different client application, your mileage may vary.

---

---

[image: sample query]

---

---

[image: settings pane]